# Opening multiple windows in tabs using a single link?

Tags: javascript

I need to open multiple windows in tabs using javascript. I know that i can open a single link in tab using target=_blank but here I can't do this.

What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there's `window.open`, to spawn a popup.

Though it works with links most of the time, I'm pretty sure it is limited on at most one popup window, otherwise the user popup blocker probably disables them.

Comment: this will open new WINDOW i need to open new TAB.

Comment: That's a browser dependency. `target=_blank` amounts to the same as opening a popup. MSIE6, for example, always shows a popup (for good reason). I'm not sure how to specify that you want a tab instead of a popup - though I know for sure many browsers (including IE, Firefox and Chrome) allow users to specify that new windows open in tabs.

Comment: the problem is i can't depend on the user's config, and i need to open multiple windows, new window instance for a single link will not be a problem but when it comes to 20+ (which is my case) then 20+ new windows are really a problem, so i need to find a solution, the code has to run on chrome only, so isn't there a hack for chrome? or will i have to just fight with my client?

Comment: Did you consider faking it? IE, opening an in-browser popup with tabs? http://blog.ticktag.org/wp-images/blogimage/2009/02/fii01-500x296.jpg http://files.nielsoeltjen.com/uploads/wp_media_management.jpg

Comment: I highly recommend using the "faking" approach - it allows for more control and customization, plus cross browser and no hacks. You can use iframes inside each tab to show a window.

Comment: if faking means open a lightbox, then i can't do it either as the new tabs are going to contain pdfs i.e the urls will be site.com/file.pdf and they will rely on pdf reader of browser.

Comment: I think you can not really 100% control how window will open. E.g. chrome opens facebook share as new tab.

Comment: hence there isn't really a solution for this

Comment: I've been able to embed PDFs nicely. Just write a wrapper script which adds the right HTTP headers which causes a PDF to be rendered. Doing this together with an iframe, the PDF is embedded.

Comment: but won't it kill the client side browser? i mean 20+ pdf files rendered in one single page

Comment: Why should it? Browsers are geared to handle such a load. Maybe use some timeouts  just in case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. See [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)